# Android ListView item layout not working

Tags: android, listview, layout

Can anyone give me a hand with this layout for my ListView items, im trying to achieve this [image]

This is my layout xml file and its not showing nothing but the date, first Team Name and Logo,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <!-- date -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#c2c2c2"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textSize="11dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dip">

            <!-- team1 -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team1"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/team_logo"
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:text="Equipo 1"
                android:textColor="#c2c2c2"
                android:typeface="sans" 
                android:textSize="13dip" />

            <!-- game_team1_logo -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/game_team1_logo"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:src="@drawable/list_placeholder"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dip">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dip">

                <!-- game_score_team1 -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_score_team1"
                    android:layout_width="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="10dip"
                    android:text=" 0 "
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:typeface="sans" 
                    android:textSize="30dip" />

                <!-- divider -->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="10dip"
                    android:text=" - "
                    android:textColor="#c2c2c2"
                    android:typeface="sans" 
                    android:textSize="30dip" />

                <!-- game_score_team2 -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/game_score_team2"
                    android:layout_width="10dip"
                    android:layout_height="10dip"
                    android:text=" 0 "
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:typeface="sans" 
                    android:textSize="30dip" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- game_status -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/game_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" FINALIZADO "
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:typeface="sans" 
                android:textSize="30dip" />

        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dip">

            <!-- team2 -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team2"
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:text="Equipo 2"
                android:textColor="#c2c2c2"
                android:typeface="sans" 
                android:textSize="13dip" />

            <!-- game_team2_logo -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/game_team2_logo"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:src="@drawable/list_placeholder"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your team1 `LinearLayout` you're using `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dip">

        <!-- team1 -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/team_logo"
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:text="Equipo 1"
            android:textColor="#c2c2c2"
            android:typeface="sans" 
            android:textSize="13dip" />

        <!-- game_team1_logo -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/game_team1_logo"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:src="@drawable/list_placeholder"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Try changing it to `wrap_content` instead. By using `fill_parent` you're forcing the other elements off the screen.

You'll also need to use `wrap_content` for the width of the other layouts.